# issue with react native run as android

Tags: react-native

i get this message when try to use npm react-native run android.

im using gradle 8.2.1

`* What went wrong:
Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'X:\react\mywallet\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\modym.gradle\caches\8.0.1\scripts\54x2qg1qm1725q098npqrdez2).

> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 64`

i don't know what is the problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.